# Particle system disasters if I edit the mesh

Tags: mesh, particles

im animating my 3d character and im wondering why when I delete any vertices from the character mesh, the particle system attached to that mesh goes all over the place.
Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas. Tested with  a new file, and I cant reproduce. Simplified your file with parts that still produce the issue and attach via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this happened with hair particles that were combed? Particle rely on faces and vertices, if you have 101 vertices and you delete no. 40, 41-100 have to change their index. Since the particles are linked to the indices, they go berserk.
The short answer: Don't do that. If you really need to remove geometry, use a **mask modifier** after the particles system.